# Force external browser from Facebook

Tags: html, facebook, google-chrome, button, browser

I need help opening links from Facebook.

I would like to create an HTML button that if clicked from Facebook mobile does not open the link on its browser, but is redirected directly to Chroome or the default mobile browser.

Can anybody help me?

So far I have tried this HTML code but it doesn't work properly.

`<a href="https://www.yoururl.com?gbOpenExternal=1">Text Button</a>`